# How do I know which version of vCard my android phone "Contacts APP" support?

Tags: android, contacts, vcf-vcard

I am basically creating a simple text file which is named `test.vcf` with below content as an example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:AAA BBB CCC
N:AAA BBB CCC
TEL;TYPE=cell:9876543210
END:VCARD
```

The above file worked when I Imported in my phone. where as below content did not work.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
FN:AAA BBB CCC
TEL;TYPE=cell:9876543210
END:VCARD
```

This is making me question which version of `vcf` file my android phone's "Contacts APP" supports.

Here is my android phone's "Contacts APP" About section

```
Contacts
Version 9.3.4.340
```

If finding the "Contacts APP" that supports the `vcf` file version is not necessary, then is there anything wrong with the content I used above for VERSION:4.0?

Comment: #thisquestionneedsananswer In general and specifically. vcf is a nightmare.  Wouldn't you think that the latest standard would be the 'best' most supported standard after so many years?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following, and it worked:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
FIRST:Firstname
LAST:Lastname
TEL:00123456798765
FN:Firstname Lastname
REV:1644704181779
END:VCARD
```

Could it be that you need the name by parts? or that something's different with the TYPE property?

I suggest trying multiple combinations, but this particular one worked for me on Android 10, using the "Contacts" app from Google. I hope it helps whoever is looking for it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

all versions are supported, but some fields will not work https://ru.frwiki.wiki/wiki/VCard